# Parse text/html data with JavaMail

Tags: java, html, jakarta-mail

I wrote an application where I fetch a message and check it's content:

```
public void getInhoud(Message msg) throws IOException, Exception {
    Object contt = msg.getContent();
    ...
    if (contt instanceof String) {
          handlePart((Part) msg);
    }
    ...
}

public void handlePart(Part part)
        throws MessagingException, IOException, Exception {

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    String contentType = part.getContentType();
    ...
    if ((contentType.length() >= 9)
            && (contentType.toLowerCase().substring(
            0, 9).equals("text/html"))) {
        part.writeTo(out);
        String stringS = out.toString();
    }
    ...
}
```

I removed the unnecessary code. This methods works for e-mail which was sent from Gmail, Hotmail and the Outlook desktop client, but somehow fails to work with e-mails which were sent from the Office 365 web client. For every other client the content type will be 'plain/text'  but only for Office 365 mail it will be `text/html`. It is writing the data of the `Part` to an `ByteArrayOutputStream` which then will be converted to a `String`. This works, well atleast the `String`  will contain the content of the part. But the HTML it contains is somewhat faulty.

Here is an example:
http://pastebin.com/5mEYCHxD (posted to Pastebin, it is pretty big).

Notice the `=` symbols which are printed at the end of almost every line. Is this something I can fix within in the code or should it be somewhere in the mailclient?

I thought about looping trough every line of HTML and removing the `=` after having checked it is not a part an HTML tag.

Any help is very much appreciated, this has been bothering me for a few weeks now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds just like [quoted printable encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable):

> Lines of quoted-printable encoded data must not be longer than 76 characters. To satisfy this requirement without altering the encoded text, soft line breaks may be added as desired. **A soft line break consists of an "=" at the end of an encoded line, and does not appear as a line break in the decoded text.**

The `writeTo` method seems to also write the encoded content, it seems you have to copy the streams yourself. The [`getInputStream` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#getInputStream%28%29) is described as returning the decoded InputStream.

Comment: That is some very useful information, thanks for that! I tried to retrieve the `InputStream` of the part like this: 
`InputStream partInput = part.getInputStream();   
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(partInput, writer);
            String stringS = writer.toString();` But somehow the `InputStream` is empty, any ideas what went wrong?

Comment: Remember that an InputStream returns **bytes** but a StringWriter writes **characters**.  At the very least you're going to need to tell is what character encoding to use to convert the byte stream to a character stream, which you can get form the "charset" parameter of the Content-Type of the part.  I don't know what IOUtils.copy is doing but trying reading the stream yourself.